# Yeast Character Resource

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature

I'm interested in locating a resource where differente yeast strains are discussed and profiled, such that for a given yeast strain I can see what different brewers' experiences have been with respect to ideal fermentation temperature, temperature effect on flavour, overall yeast effect on flavour, etc. I know certain manufacturers provide some of this information, but the effect of temperature on flavour per yeast strain I have found hard to come by: is this not unique to different yeasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked your idea so much, I went ahead and made a site that does this! :)

You can find it at [www.yeasthub.com](http://www.yeasthub.com).

It's very rough around the edges (i've only been working on it a few days), but any comments and feedback would be most appreciated.

Comments/reviews/notes on the yeasts would be even more appreciated. :)

Comment: You rock! I was hoping someone would do this if there wasn't already such a resource around. I'll go peruse your site and I'll be sure to provide any feedback I have. Cheers!

Comment: Couldn't find an email to contact you by, so I'll provide my feedback here: two things. 1) The Google Sign On is broken, something about a re-direct link. 2) I think it'd be helpful to list the yeast in numerical order.

Comment: Hi ya, sorry about the Google error - that should be fixed now. Try again and let me know how you get on. :)  One of the things i've got in the todo list is to be able to sort the yeasts on any of the criteria, so i'll get to that as soon as I can.  You can search for a product number (in the search on the top-right) though if that helps.  My email is daz.oakley@gmail.com if you've got any other ideas/comments. :)

Comment: Is this website no longer active? is there a new URL? just seen this and it sounds like it would be very useful!

Comment: Afraid not - it was there for nearly 3 years, and not a single comment or post (apart from ones from myself) :( so I took it offline a little while back.  All the yeast data etc is available quite widely on the internet these days, here's some useful links: https://byo.com/resources/yeast , http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/homebrew/listings , https://www.wyeastlab.com/hb_yeaststrain.cfm

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you want, but if you use White Labs yeast, they have pretty good info on their site (http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/homebrew_strains.html) along with customer reviews for each strain.

Comment: Yea, I like the White Labs resource, that's who I was referring to as 'certain manufacturers' in my question, but I'm looking for something different from that.

Answer (score 2):

Yeast is a tricky little thing, and a good yeast resource including a collection of several yeast company would be nice. On one hand it would be a bit redundant because different companies use the same or very similar strain of yeast but have their own name for it, but on the other hand it would be nice to look up specifically the yeast you use. And as a general rule the warmer the fermentation the more estery (Banana, clove, "Belgiany") your beer will turn out. I know that doesn't help much but I think at this point a whole lot of research and brewing is your best bet, I listen to a lot of podcasts on brewing and that is really helpful... GOOD LUCK